# I keep getting 'MainWindow' does not contain a definition for 'FadeOut' in Visual Studio WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I'm trying to make a Lua Executor and I am getting this error:

```
'MainWindow' does not contain a definition for 'FadeOut' and no accessible extension method 'FadeOut' accepting a first argument of type 'MainWindow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

This is part of the code I'm getting the error from:

```
        private async void Grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Fade(this.Logo);
        ObjectShift(Logo, Logo.Margin, new Thickness(247, 72, 0, 0));
        await Task.Delay(350);
        ObjectShift(Logo, Logo.Margin, new Thickness(247, 200, 0, -53));
        this.FadeOut(this.Logo);
        await Task.Delay(100);
        Executor exec = new Executor();
        exec.Show();
    }
```

This part of the code will make the 'Logo' Fade and after 350 ms it will Fade out. Then open a new Page called 'Executor'. But for some reason it keeps saying `'MainWindow' does not contain a definition for 'FadeOut...'` . Even though it works for my other friends.

Here is all the code I have type so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace The3Akuma
{    
  /// <summary>
  /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
  /// </summary>
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
   {
     Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
     TimeSpan duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);
     TimeSpan duration2 = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);

     private IEasingFunction Smooth
     {
        get;
        set;
     }
     = new QuarticEase
     {
        EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseInOut
     };
     public void Fade(DependencyObject Object)
     {
        DoubleAnimation Fade = new DoubleAnimation()
        {
            From = 0.0,
            To = 1.0,
            Duration = new Duration(duration),
        };
        Storyboard.SetTarget(Fade, Object);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(Fade, new PropertyPath("Opacity", 1));
        storyboard.Children.Add(Fade);
        storyboard.Begin();
    }


    public void ObjectShift(DependencyObject Object, Thickness Get, Thickness Set)
    {
        ThicknessAnimation Animation = new ThicknessAnimation()
        {
            From = Get,
            To = Set,
            Duration = duration2,
        EasingFunction = Smooth,
        };
        Storyboard.SetTarget(Animation, Object);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(Animation, new PropertyPath(MarginProperty));
        storyboard.Children.Add(Animation);
        storyboard.Begin();
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void Grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Fade(this.Logo);
        ObjectShift(Logo, Logo.Margin, new Thickness(247, 72, 0, 0));
        await Task.Delay(350);
        ObjectShift(Logo, Logo.Margin, new Thickness(247, 200, 0, -53));
        this.FadeOut(this.Logo);
        await Task.Delay(100);
        Executor exec = new Executor();
        exec.Show();
   }
}
```

^ that Bracket didn't went inside the the code thing for some reasons.

### More Info:

1. I'm Using Visual Studio 2022
2. Language = C#
3. Using WPF
4. Trying to make a Lua Executor
5. 'FadeOut' is not a definition on 'MainWindow'

Anyways that's the error I'm getting, Quick Note: I'm kind of new to Visual Studio and C#.

Hopefully the the information I gave is enough to fix the code, If you need more information Please feel free to ask me!

Comment: As the error says, you are missing the definition of the Fadeout method.

Answer (score 1):

As your message says: You don't have a method with the name FadeOut inside your MainWindow Class.

You have to define one like

```
public void FadeOut(DependencyObject Object)
{
// Your Code here
}
```